Efficiently repeating a smaller integer/bit pattern in C
Suppose I have an object comprising many small integer types. For example, an octree branch comprising 8 uint16_t:
uint16_t values[8];

I would like to assign them all to a single value. The obvious solution is to use a loop:
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    values[i] = new_value;

However, is there a way I can write this without looping or otherwise assigning them one-by-one? Are there SWAR or similar tricks to perform this task in fewer than 8 steps?
I am allowed to pack values[8] into a union with other larger types.
I tried compiling a loop and assigning each value individually under the assumption that the compiler with optimizations enabled would recognize the pattern but I still get the sub-optimal 'linear' algorithm of assigning each value one-by-one.

This is a Q&A intended to document my known solutions, but if someone has yet another one, or has something to add, feel free to add your own answer.

Re "However, is there a way I can write this without looping", No. Doing something repeatedly requires some kind of loop by definition.

@ikegami You could assign them one by one without a loop, values[0] = new_value; values[1] = new_value; values[2] = new_value; // ...

A simple-enough macro involving bit shifting could be used uint64_t t[2] = { MACRO( n ) }; Can't be fussed to write it out. Sorry...

Turn on optimization.  If a fully unrolled loop would be faster, the optimizer will likely do that.  If vectorization would help, that will generally be used too.

If the smaller type in question is a unsigned char or type with the same representation, one option is to simply use memset():
uint8_t values[8];
memset(values, new_value, 8);

Performance will depend on the compiler and implementation. Any reasonable compiler should recognize library calls such as memset() and generate optimal code for them.

If the type in question is larger than unsigned char, that rules out memset() but a couple of other ways come to mind.
You can use type-punning to, rather than assign a value every time, assign the first 2 individually, then reinterpret the first 2 as a larger type, to assign the first 2 to the second 2 in one step, and so on:
union Components {
    uint16_t u16[8];
    uint32_t u32[4];
    uint64_t u64[2];
} values;
values.u16[1] = values.u16[0] = new_value;
values.u32[1] = values.u32[0];
values.u64[1] = values.u64[0];

A similar effect can be used with bitwise operators:
uint64_t value = new_value;
value |= value << 16;
value |= value << 32;

In a sense, the above has a logarithmic number of steps if the number of copies made fits within a single register.

The final way is to simply use multiplication by a magic number. Binary multiplication is equivalent to, for each bit in a number, adding either 0 if the bit is 0, otherwise the other number shifted by the bit position, to the result. As such, we can exploit this by producing masks which comprise 0 bits for all bits except the start of wherever we want a copy of our original number.
uint8_t new_value;
uint64_t values = 0x0101010101010101U * new_value; // 8 copies of new_value concatenated together

uint16_t new_value;
uint64_t values = 0x0001000100010001U * new_value; // 4 copies of new_value concatenated together

The actual 16-bit values can be individually accessed in array form using a union similar to the second example:
union Components values;
values.u64[1] = values.u64[0] = 0x0001000100010001U * new_value; // This can be made even better if you have a futuristic machine with 128-bit registers

(Example demo)

If you are allowed to use SSE2 intrinsics, you can use _mm_set1_epi16(new_value) or _mm_set1_epi8(new_value) for 16 or 8 bit new_values respectively. You can wrap it in an #ifdef _SSE2__ for portability (Visual Studio excepted).

Note: The multiplication technique is marginally better than the copying-twice-as-much-each-time method when used on memory, but is vastly the superior option when being used within a register. Both are significantly superior than the individual method.
